# How to use raw mysql statement in the migration file of laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, migration, database-migration

I have a mysql statement ：

> 'SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";'

I want to run it in a migration file  of laravel 5.4 ,but I don't konw what should to do?

The following  is my migration file's  partial content:

```
> public function up()
>     {
>         //
>         Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
> 
>             // SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"
>             // todo 
> 
>             $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
>             $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
>             $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
> 
>             $table->int('id',11)->comment('ID');
>             $table->string('name',50)->nullable()->comment('name');
>             $table->string('phone',20);
>             ...
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

> You can use `DB::statement`

Try below

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
       DB::statement('SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";');
       //run other migrations 
   }
}
```